# MVC identitiy || How can i implment my own or override the [Authorize] data notation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity

How can I override/implement my own `[Authorize]` and `User.isInRole()`?

The code of `[Authorize]` and `User.isInRole()` isn't shown anywhere maybe someone could give me the code of it? 
 or tell me how can I override this method?

I read some articles saying its not good to override this method because its lead to a lot of problem with the caches and things like that.

So maybe I'll just implement my own method but i want to know how thoese method works so i can take from there what i need.

**My motivation** to do it is that I added a field of called "Active" its use to activate and deactivate users( the admin will do it) so i want to check this field in the DB before returning "True" for checking user Authorization.

**Use-Case:** If the user loged-in and he is authenticated but in my database the "active" field of the user is 0(and not 1) all this methods:

`[Authorize]`

`User.isInRole()`

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

will return false(= the user is not authenticated).

How can i do it ? if someone have implment it before i aprricate if he can post his code to let me see ecatly what i need to do.

Thanks A lot

**One last thing:** Because i only need to add one line of code to the original method maybe there is away to get to the code of the original method and add my line(get a value of the field from the DB) ?

Comment: Just user default `[Authorize(Roles = "Active")]` - it checks if user is logged in and if user is in role "Active". And don't login guys who are not Active.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: MVC 4.0 & identitiy 2.0

Comment: @trailmax its one way to do it.